# How to iterate through all elements in a list with Erlang

Tags: loops, for-loop, erlang

I'm new to Erlang. All I want to do is take a list, loop through each element so I can send them to a function. Cannot find a clear example anywhere.

Example of what I want to do:

```
Mylist = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

for (i in Mylist) {
  otherFunction(Mylist[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Hope that help :)

```
func([]) -> ok;
func([H|T]) ->
    otherFunction(H),
    func(T).
```

Or you can use list comprehension:

```
[otherFunction(H) || H <- L].
```

Comment: Thanks!

I also figured out: lists:foreach(fun(X) -> otherFuntion(X) end, MyList)
for anyone else reading this and in the same situation.

Comment: `lists:foreach` is not very idiomatic (as in imperative than functional). It's normally used for creating side effects like spawning a process for each element in the source list.

Comment: The second definition of `func([])` gives me the following compile error:
`function func/1 already defined`.
How should I solve it? Thank you

Comment: it's because it should be ```func([]) -> ok;
func([H|T]) ->
    otherFunction(H),
    func(T).```

Take care of the ; at the end of the clause version of func/1 but not the end of all version of the same function

Answer (score 8):

You may use `lists:foreach`

```
L = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g],
Function = fun(Elem) -> atom_to_binary(Elem, utf8) end,
lists:foreach(Function, L).
```

Or if you need to receive some result from the function you may use `lists:foldl` or `lists:foldr`

```
L = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g],
F = fun(Elem, Acc) -> [atom_to_binary(Elem, utf8) | Acc] end,
lists:foldl(F, [], L).
```

Response will be

```
[<<"g">>,<<"f">>,<<"e">>,<<"d">>,<<"c">>,<<"b">>,<<"a">>]
```